# Cross browser numbers only search bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there a cross browser solution that allows only numbers in my search bar? I've tried `type="numbers"` but it seems to mess up my search bar. `Javascript` and `JQuery` welcome.

Here's the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/W742e/1/

Comment: _"applying a set numbers only field in my search bar?"_ what does that mean?

Comment: @gdoron Update: "Is there a cross browser solution that allows only numbers in my search bar"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `type="number"` but do not want the default styling that comes with it you can use.

```
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none; 
    margin: 0;   
}
```

**html**

```
<input type="number"></input>
```

And this will remove the spinners in Chrome and Safari.

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W742e/4/)

Comment: To enter this in css do I use `input.numbers`?

Comment: This css will be applied to all inputs with the type attribute "number".

Comment: Just enter it as it is. No `input.numbers`. See fiddle in answer.

Comment: See my fiddle in the answer.  You need to update your css style `#search-box-4 input[type="text"]` to `#search-box-4 input[type="number"]`

Comment: is there a min and max length that is cross browser as well